# Return a template instantiation based on file content

Tags: c++

I need to read a file with raw binary data, with a header to indicate whether the data should be interpreted as integers, floats, doubles, and so on (it'll always be a numeric type). However I would also like to use a template class to hold that data inside the program, like so:

```
#include <filesystem>

template <typename T>
struct Foo;

Foo open(const std::filesystem::path& path);
```

This won't work, although I do know all possible types T could possibly be, I can't know what specific type T is gonna be until I open the file at runtime. I guess one way to deal with this problem would be by defining a pure virtual interface and returning a pointer like this:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <memory>

class IFoo;

template <typename T>
struct Foo : public IFoo
{
    //...
};

std::unique_ptr<IFoo> open(const std::filesystem::path& path);
```

This is somewhat inconvenient, if I need to later access a member variable of type T (or member function that returns `Something<T>`) I can't include those in the interface, I'd need to find some way to convert `IFoo` back into `Foo<T>` afterwards.

Another thing I could do is a widening conversion, always return a `Foo<long long>` or `Foo<double>` and throwing an exception if the integer method is called on a floating point data file or the reverse, and/or maybe adding another function that looks at the file and determines whether it has floating point or integer data before calling `open`. The file could be quite large though so using 4x as much memory because I needlessly converted all those 16 bit integers into 64 bit integers is also undesirable.

Maybe just holding a vector of bytes with an enum indicating the type might be the most convenient after all?

```
enum class NumType
{
    Int16,
    Int32,
    Float32,
    Float64,
    //...
};

struct Foo
{
    NumType type;
    std::vector<char> data;
    //...
};

Foo open(const std::filesystem::path& path);
```

Anyway, is there some better alternative I'm missing?

Comment: `std::variant` is your case.

Comment: Templates are purely compile-time things, while files are purely run-time things. They can't be combined.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can always use a runtime value to dispatch to a compile-time type via something like a factory method.

Comment: For me this question is good example of [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). To get a good answer you should restate your question. For example you should describe data format you are trying to read (maybe there is ready solution for that data format). You should also explain why you think you need a single function which should return multiple types. Why not use some callbacks like in case of SAX parsers?

Comment: What you're proposing looks like _erasure type_ which can be a good idea, but you can also consider other good advices above.
The best solution will depend on your use case, which we don't know precisely enough.

Comment: @MarekR It's a somewhat particular format which I have no control over how it's generated and I doubt there's a ready solution out there (at least not a popular open source one). I just need the data to calculate some stuff and pass some information to another process, so I think std::variant with a few overflow checks fits my problem.

Comment: Are all of the entries in your file the same type, or can one file contain a combination of int32, float32, etc.?

Comment: Different files might have different types, but the data of a single file can only be of one type. The file has a header and a bunch of binary data, the header says how the binary data must be interpreted. It's not exactly the same but you could compare it to a bmp format.